# Editing floating textbox using python-docx or editing document.xml?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, floating, python-docx

I'm editing a docx template that contains a bunch of floating images and textboxes. I'm trying to edit these text boxes through python-docx or directly editing the document.xml. However, it seems the current iteration of python-docx only allows editing of inline "pictures"(in this case textbox). The end goal is to either edit the textbox using python-docx or edit it by accessing and editing the document.xml (ideally without unzipping and then zipping back up)

So far, I have attempted to use python-docx to edit these but from my research, the textbox cannot be edited using python-docx.

I have also tried just editing the document.xml separately which I was successfully able to do however when I attempted to zip back up the directories and change the extension back to a docx I was unable to open it.

```
import lxml.etree as ET

xmlfile = r"path\document.xml"

with open(xmlfile) as f:
  tree = ET.parse(f)
  root = tree.getroot()


  for elem in root.getiterator():
    try:
      elem.text = elem.text.replace('current id in document', 'new ID in document')
    except AttributeError:
      pass

tree.write(r"path\documentedit.xml", xml_declaration=True, method='xml')
```

This was my first unzipping the docx without using python. Then use python to edit the XML. Then I would zip it up without using python just to see if I could get it to work but I was unable to open the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of details involved in getting an Open Packaging Convention (OPC) package opened up and back in the form in needs to be for Word to open it.

You can use `python-docx` to access the XML directly, while still leaving the details of proper saving (or "re-packaging") to `python-docx`.

If you're using `lxml`, you can get the XML for the document part as an `lxml.etree._Element` object using `document._element`. Whatever changes you make to that XML tree will be saved when you call `document.save()`.

The other alternative is to access the XML text directly with `document.part.blob`. A changed version can be assigned (as a Python 2 str/ Python 3 bytes) to `document.part._blob` (note leading underscore) and will be saved when you call `document.save()`.

This avoids you having to deal with all the intricacies of packaging.

Comment: Thanks, I realized earlier in the code the initial template that is copied over to my workspace was already unpackaged(unzipped) so I editied the doument.xml directly from that using lxml far earlier in the code and only needed to package once. The above suggestion is helpful for anyone looking to avoid packaging/repackaging at all. Some code example would be useful. I've seen your posts on many other topics related to python-docx

Comment: ```document.save()``` is not saving changed contents. However, ```document.part._blob``` is changed. What could be the reason?

Comment: @scanny I can access .docx with `document.part.blob`, but how can i modify the content?